How to read from csv and generate excel file with same name python
Currently i am reading sql queries from column in csv file, executing them in Snowflake and then generating sql query result in separate excel file for every query. The code is working fine.
The excel files are generating with filename as result_1.xlsx, result_2.xlsx. But now i want to create excel file with filename as provided in second column of csv file.
Below is my python code:
# Read queries from the CSV file with UTF-8 encoding to remove BOM
with open(csv_file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    queries = [row[0] for row in reader if row]  # Skip empty rows

# Execute each query and save results to separate Excel files
for i, query in enumerate(queries):
    try:
        # Execute the query using SQLAlchemy engine
        df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
       
        # Define the output Excel file name
        output_file = os.path.join(output_directory, f'result_{i + 1}.xlsx')
       
        # Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
        df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
        print(f'Saved results of query {i + 1} to {output_file}')
       
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error executing query {i + 1}: {e}")


I think you can read the second column directly
# Read queries from the CSV file with UTF-8 encoding to remove BOM
with open(csv_file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    queries = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in reader if row]  # Skip empty rows

    # Execute each query and save results to separate Excel files
    for i, (query, filename) in enumerate(queries):
        try:
            # Execute the query using SQLAlchemy engine
            df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
       
            # Define the output Excel file name
            output_file = os.path.join(output_directory, f'{filename}.xlsx')
       
            # Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
            df.to_excel(output_file, index=False)
            print(f'Saved results of query {i + 1} to {output_file}')
       
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error executing query {i + 1}: {e}")

My changes were queries = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in reader if row], for i, (query, filename) in enumerate(queries): and output_file = os.path.join(output_directory, f'{filename}.xlsx')

In python, you can skip the first row like reader[1:] and keep everything else the same. Example:
queries = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in reader[1:] if row]

TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable i am getting this error

it works with     reader = list(csv.reader(file))
